# Error preparsing a xsd file with xercesc

Tags: c++, xerces-c

i'm trying to preparsing a xsd file with xerces-c to use the GrammarPool in a multi-thread application. The problem is that i preparsed the xsd correctly (no one notification of my error handler) but when i parse a valid xml file (checked that is valid with an online validator) the parsing failed telling me that the attributes and elements have not been declared.
Now i'll show you my code to preparse the file.

```
XMLGrammarPool gp = new XMLGrammarPoolImpl (XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager);
XercesDOMParser* parser = new XercesDOMParser(0, XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager, gp);
parser->cacheGrammarFromParse(true);
error_handler eh;
parser->setErrorHandler(&eh);
parser->setDoSchema(true);
parser->setDoNamespaces(true);
if(!parser->loadGrammar("file.xsd", Grammar::SchemaGrammarType, true) || eh.failed()){
    delete gp;
    XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
    return -6;
}
gp->lockPool();
```

and this is for parse the xml file:

```
XercesDOMParser *parser = new XercesDOMParser(0, XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager, gp);
error_handler eh;
parser->setErrorHandler(&eh);

parser->setValidationSchemaFullChecking(true);
parser->setIgnoreAnnotations(true);
parser->setCreateCommentNodes(false);
parser->useCachedGrammarInParse(true);
parser->setValidationScheme(AbstractDOMParser::ValSchemes::Val_Always);

MemBufInputSource buf((const XMLByte*)xml_file, size, "xml_file in memory");

parser->parse(buf);
if(eh.failed()){
    delete parser;
    return;
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The blog entry

[Multi-threaded XML parsing with Xerces-C++](http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2010/01/25/multi-threaded-xml-parsing-validation-xerces-cxx/)

explains how to reuse a cached schema in a multi-threaded application. The blog is called *A Sense of Design* and it is written by Boris Kolpackov.

I also recommend taking a look into this Public Domain C++ file (also by the same author)

http://scm.codesynthesis.com/?p=xsd/xsd.git;a=blob;f=examples/cxx/tree/performance/parsing.cxx;hb=HEAD

It shows us how to have Xerces parse the schema once and then read a number of XML files. Some parts of the implementation are related to [CodeSynthesis XSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/) so you will need to modify it somewhat.